# Apache adds "./" to file names with colons in them

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, url

I ran in to this today running httpd on Centos 7.3.  We do a lot of raw getting of apache-generated HTML docs for file download.  Apparently, **if a file name has a colon, apache well prepend "./" to the file name within the HTML**.  This tripped up our scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /some_path/dir</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /some_path/dir</h1>
<pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                                                                                                                                               <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <hr><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"> <a href="/some_path">Parent Directory</a>
<img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"> <a href="./file1:has_colon.bios">file1:has_colon.bios</a> 2018-04-03 07:13  234K
<img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"> <a href="./file2:has_colon.bios">file2:has_colon.bios</a> 2018-04-03 07:13  234K
<img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"> <a href="file3_has_no_colon.bios">file3_has_no_colon.bios</a> 2018-04-03 07:13  234K
<hr></pre>
</body></html>
```

Does anyone know why this is?  Is there some kind of name enforcement it's doing?  And, can I turn it off?

**Edit**

As is pointed out below, this is due to URI naming conventions.  I found the following helpful for beginning understanding:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done to prevent what is a *relative* URI from being misinterpreted as an *absolute* URI with an unknown scheme. It is *not* something you want to turn off, as the breakage would be even worse. Fixing your script to deal with this should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right that it's trivial to fix - that's the way we're going to handle it.